# Serialized attributes not coming back as proper objects

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, serialization, deserialization

I have a serialized attribute in my model `serialize :vertices, Array`. All seems OK when using it, but after I reload the console (or on a web request) the serialized array is returned as a string, which is obviously not what I expected. Here is the same procedure in rails console:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :009 > g.vertices = [Vertex.new, Vertex.new]
 => [#<Vertex:0x000000036315e8 @neighbours={}, @options={}, @name=nil, @real_name=nil, @teacher=nil, @discipline=nil, @student_group=nil>, #<Vertex:0x00000003631458 @neighbours={}, @options={}, @name=nil, @real_name=nil, @teacher=nil, @discipline=nil, @student_group=nil>] 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :010 > g.inspect
 => "#<Graph id: 17, vertices: [#<Vertex:0x000000036315e8 @neighbours={}, @options={}, @name=nil, @real_name=nil, @teacher=nil, @discipline=nil, @student_group=nil>, #<Vertex:0x00000003631458 @neighbours={}, @options={}, @name=nil, @real_name=nil, @teacher=nil, @discipline=nil, @student_group=nil>], oriented: true, max_index: 0, trigger_limit: nil, created_at: \"2011-11-01 09:13:40\", updated_at: \"2011-11-01 09:17:30\", name: nil>" 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :011 > g.save
   (0.4ms)  UPDATE "graphs" SET "vertices" = '---
- !ruby/object:Vertex
 neighbours: {}
 options: {}
 name: !!null 
 real_name: !!null 
 teacher: !!null 
 discipline: !!null 
 student_group: !!null 
- !ruby/object:Vertex
 neighbours: {}
 options: {}
 name: !!null 
 real_name: !!null 
 teacher: !!null 
 discipline: !!null 
 student_group: !!null 
', "updated_at" = '2011-11-01 09:21:11.516199' WHERE "graphs"."id" = 17
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :012 > g.inspect
 => "#<Graph id: 17, vertices: [#<Vertex:0x000000036315e8 @neighbours={}, @options={}, @name=nil, @real_name=nil, @teacher=nil, @discipline=nil, @student_group=nil>, #<Vertex:0x00000003631458 @neighbours={}, @options={}, @name=nil, @real_name=nil, @teacher=nil, @discipline=nil, @student_group=nil>], oriented: true, max_index: 0, trigger_limit: nil, created_at: \"2011-11-01 09:13:40\", updated_at: \"2011-11-01 09:21:11\", name: nil>" 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :013 > reload!
Reloading...
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :014 > g = Graph.last
  Graph Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "graphs".* FROM "graphs" ORDER BY "graphs"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Graph id: 17, vertices: "---\n- !ruby/object:Vertex\n  neighbours: {}\n  option...", oriented: true, max_index: 0, trigger_limit: nil, created_at: "2011-11-01 09:13:40", updated_at: "2011-11-01 09:21:11", name: nil> 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :015 > g.vertices.class
 => String 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :016 >
```

I guess its not deserializing properly (maybe because of my custom classes in the array?) Any tips would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Saving serialized Ruby instances isn't exactly elegant. I'd recommend a more orthodox approach using for example `composed_of`, or any other solution that actually saves the arguments to build the instance into the DB and not the instance itself:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Aggregations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Yeah, its definitely not the most beautiful solution, but I didn't want to create thousands of vertex objects and put them into the DB if its only used for some calculations. Still I was wondering, why shouldn't it work? Its classical serializing of objects ( Would it work if I saved strings or hashes or some other generic stucture? )